# Gravity cause wavefunction collapse? (Roger penrose)

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-tunneling

Roger Penrose suggested that gravity might play a role in the collapse of the wave function (which describes a system as a superposition of multiple values of Position, momentum etc.). According to Penrose’s proposal, while electrons might stay in superposition for years, gravity sets a limit for massive particles, implying that anything on a macroscopic scale collapses immediately. Therefore, for systems above a certain mass, quantum behavior vanishes.

Is this true and accurate?
It is real world?
Does gravity directly cause quantum decoherence?  Does gravity cause irreversible interactions with the environment?

Comment: Can you please provide a citation for "Penrose's proposal." Your description of it is seemingly flawed. For example, you seem to differentiate between "electrons" and "massive particles," but electrons are massive particles (in the sense that they have mass).

Comment: "Is this true and accurate? It is real world?" Probably not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @hft See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_interpretation .

Comment: @hft Does gravity directly cause quantum decoherence?  Does gravity cause irreversible interactions with the environment?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I would have written an answer. Based on the link I would suspect both those questions are currently unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

It's a viable sketch of a proposal for how gravity might be responsible for quantum wave function collapse.  Even Penrose admitted that it's only a sketch  and not a full-fledged model.  And we can't know whether it corresponds to the real world until we do the appropriate experiment, though Penrose did propose an actual experiment that is within reach in the near future:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-orbit_experiment_with_laser_interferometry_X-rays